# TypeScript compiler replaces simple inferred types with random dependency imports

Tags: typescript, tsc

We're seeing simple inferred types like `string|number` being replaced by types from dependencies 
 in our output declaration files... so `string|number` turns into `import("csstype").AnimationIterationCountPropert` in our `d.ts` files.

This causes strange, out of context intellisense names, and can cause issues in monorepos if symlinked packages don't have access to the dependency the TS compiler decides to use.

Here's an example of a function that could return a string or a number:

```
    const myFunc = (test: boolean) => {
      let returnString = 'something';
      let returnNumber = 1234;
      // Returns either string or number
      return test ? returnString : returnNumber;
    };
```

**TS Inferred type:** If you check the VSCode tooltip, the type for this function is:

`(method) myFunc(test: boolean): string | number`

**Compiled Declaration:** Everything looks good so far. Let's use `tsc` to compile this. Here is the output in `myFunc.d.ts`:

`myFunc(test: boolean): import("csstype").AnimationIterationCountProperty`.

**What?!** My source file didn't even include `csstype` or make any mention to it. `AnimationIterationCountProperty` does happen to also share the type `string|number`, so I'm guessing the TS compiler is trying to re-use its type since it shares the same signature?

This causes 2 problems:

1. The code consuming this library doesn't necessarily have `csstype` in its node_modules, which causes an error.
2. In the consuming code, my intellisense when I mouse over `myFunc` says the return type is `AnimationIterationCountProperty` which makes no sense in the context. This function has nothing to do with CSS types.

Is this intended behavior from the TS compiler? Or is this some sort of bug? Thanks for any help.

---

Additional info:

1. Typescript 3.6.3
2. If I explictly type the function with the return type `string|number`, this doesn't happen. It outputs the expected type.
3. Here is our tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "strict": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "declaration": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["**/__tests__/**"]
}
```

Comment: Hmm, looks like a [design limitation in TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30759#issuecomment-480051225)

Comment: Wow, great find. That's wild.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a design limitation of the TypeScript compiler.

For union types, the compiler will re-use the first name it finds for a particular combination (?!?).

Credit to @jcalz for finding this GitHub issue:
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30759#issuecomment-480051225